# Why does this error message show when I try to download a package?

Tags: r, download, package

I am currently trying to download a couple of packages via BiocManagerBiocManager::install("gplots")

But this error message shows up:

> Error in unpackPkgZip(foundpkgs[okp, 2L], foundpkgs[okp, 1L], lib, libs_only,  :
> ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\Linap\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2’ for modifying
> Try removing ‘C:\Users\Linap\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2/00LOCK’

Why does it say that and how do I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try restarting R (or RStudio), remove the directory specified in the error message, then try installing again.

Comment: It says to try deleting "C:\Users\Linap\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2/00LOCK"
but I don't know how to locate the directory, I tried to search for it among my files but nothing showed up

Comment: On Windows the AppData directory is usually hidden. You need to go to "C:\Users\Linap" in the File Explorer, click "View" and check "Hidden items".

Comment: Another method to start navigating `AppData/Local/...`: open `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, either in the "Run" dialog or the address/path portion of a Windows Explorer window.